# Php get timestamp of previous day midnight

Tags: php

Am trying to get the timestamp of previous day midnight

That is if today is thursday ,  get the timestamp of wednesday midnight.

How do i go about this

i have tried

```
$lastdaymidnight = strtotime() //am stuck
```

What do i need to add to strtotime?

Comment: `$lastdaymidnight = strtotime("today midnight -1 day");` maybe?

Comment: speaking of midnight; it's my time to hit the hay. If that works, great ^

Comment: if you want get timestamp only, you use strtotime('yesterday midnight')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp(strtotime('yesterday midnight'));
```

Comment: +50 for using the datetime class over strtotime

Comment: Note that this will return Wednesday 12:00am

Comment: You can also do this on one line by passing the string into the `DateTime` constructor:

`$date = new DateTime('yesterday midnight');`

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```php
$date = new DateTime('yesterday midnight');
```